# Android Fingerprint Sensor

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

How do I listen to Fingerprint onTouch event. I tried Fingerprint Authentication Event, which is working well but as soon as I got success response from Authentication it will stop listening on Fingerprint Sensor.

I want something which continually listen on Fingerprint Sensor.

Comment: _"I want something which continually listen on Fingerprint Sensor."_ For what purpose? The only thing you can use the sensor for with the official API is to perform authentications (i.e. make a crypographic key available for use if the fingerprint matches any of the enrolled fingerprints).

Comment: I would like to use as button for extra functionality

Comment: Are you trying to create a button and make the authenticate() method called in the onClick() method of the button?